# Creating procedures in phpPgadmin

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, phppgadmin

I want create a procedure (for copying the values of one table(`mover_location`) to another table(`mover_history`) on updation)  ,and want to call up on that on a trigger in postgresql with phppgadmin.

Here is what i have tried :

**PROCEDURE :-**

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_mover_location()
     RETURNS trigger AS

    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO mover_history(reg_id,last_seen_lat,last_seen_long,last_seen_location_geog,last_updated_at)
    VALUES(SELECT 

    mover_location.reg_id,mover_location.last_seen_lat,mover_location.last_seen_long,mover_location.last_seen_location_geog,mover_location.last_updated_at FROM mover_location) WHERE mover_history.reg_id = 

    @mover_location.reg_id;

    END;
```

**TRIGGER :-**

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_mover_history
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON mover_location
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE log_mover_location();
```

Trigger created successfully ,

But it give me a error as follows when executing the procedure:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 4: BEGIN
        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

the Procedure that you're created is incorrect, for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION procedure_name()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
/*----logic----*/
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Comment: Now the error falls on SELECT as ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 6: VALUES(SELECT mover_location.reg_id,mover_location.last_seen...
               ^